# Java - Enums - Logical circular reference

Tags: java, enums, circular-reference, forward-reference

Imagine the following made up example:

```
public enum Hand {
  ROCK(SCISSORS),
  PAPER(ROCK),
  SCISSORS(PAPER);

  private final Hand beats;

  Hand(Hand beats) {
    this.beats = beats;
  }
}
```

I will get an error `Illegal forward reference` for forward referencing `SCISSORS`.

---

Is there a way to handle such forward references in Java?

Or how would you model such a situation, where you have a logical circular reference between several enums values?

Comment: Which error? please specify

Comment: Updated with `Illegal forward reference` error information.

Comment: You can use a `switch` inside a method.

Comment: I actually take it back. This is a duplicate... of the first result from the google search of 'Cannot reference a field before it is defined'

Comment: I recommend you to read http://brickydev.com/enum-circular-dependency-in-java/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot assign `SCISSORS` to `ROCK` before it is defined. You can, instead, assign the values in a static block.

I have seen a lot examples where people use String values in the constructors, but this is more concrete to assign the actual values after they have been declared. This is encapsulated and the `beats` instance variable cannot be changed (unless you use reflection).

```java
public enum Hand {
    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS;

    private Hand beats;

    static {
        ROCK.beats = SCISSORS;
        PAPER.beats = ROCK;
        SCISSORS.beats = PAPER;
    }

    public Hand getBeats() {
        return beats;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Hand hand : Hand.values()) {
            System.out.printf("%s beats %s%n", hand, hand.getBeats());
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
ROCK beats SCISSORS
PAPER beats ROCK
SCISSORS beats PAPER
```

Comment: Why downvoted this? It actually looks good to me

Comment: The code before the edit did not work because of the `final` modifier on the `beats` field.